# Merging arrays, adding array as dimension to existing array

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say i have 2 arrays

Array1

```
array($info)

$info['id'] => some id
$info['text'] => some text
etc
```

lets say i have a function that returns another array called images

Array 2

```
array($images)

$images[0] => some link 1
$images[1] => some link 2
etc
```

How do i add $images to the $info array as a new dimension, as such

```
$info['image'][0] => some link 1
$info['image'][1] => some link 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess that's only a matter of:

```
$info['image'] = $images;
```

Comment: ^^ deleted my answer - this one is actually what you're after. You would then iterate this array field to display them